# Product release approval assigned to one team for different Azure DevOps project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

We have multiple teams using different projects (Customer Team1, Customer Team 2 etc) in the Azure DevOps organization for the development and deployment of APIs. Those APIs are deploying to API Management service also. Now all teams are deploying their APIs themselves to different environments such as DEV, TEST and PROD.

We want to control the deployment to the PROD environment, by assigning approvers from our team (Team A) so that other team should wait for our team's review and approval before deploying to production.

Can anyone tell me how can we do it? What are the different access given to each team? (Team A, Customer Team1, Customer Team2)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a team or a user as a pre-defined approvals following this official document: [Define a Classic release pipeline - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops#add-pre-deployment-approvals)

The Teams or users can be found in the list of search box in multiple projects under one organization like below:

[image]